# Can I pass a variable to a composable function, and get the content in remember to be updated as well without reconstructing everything?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple Composable function below

```
@Composable
fun MyComposableFun(textValue: String) {

    val myComposeView = remember {
        MyComposable().apply {
            setContent { Text(textValue) }
        }
    }

    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
        Text("Title: $textValue")
        myComposeView.myComposable?.invoke()
    }
}

class MyComposable {
    var myComposable: (@Composable () -> Unit)? = null

    fun setContent(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
        myComposable = content
    }
}
```

When the `textValue` is changed, it only affects the

```
Text("Title: $textValue")
```

But not the

```
setContent { Text(textValue) }
```

Is there any way I can get it to apply to both?

**p/s: (I understand it doesn't apply to `setContent { Text(textValue) }` because it is wrapped in `remember`. But I'm trying to see if there's a way to get it applied into `remember` as well.**

Approaches I tried

#### 1. Use `remember(textValue)` to change reconstruct the entire `MyComposable` again.

I can use

```
    val myComposeView = remember(textValue) {
        MyComposable().apply {
            setContent { Text(textValue) }
        }
    }
```

But it's not ideal, as it will recreate a new copy of `Mycomposable()`.

#### 2. Construct a new state variable from `textValue`

I try using `val newTextValue by remember(textValue) { mutableStateOf(textValue) }`, i.e.

```
@Composable
fun MyComposableFun(textValue: String) {

    val newTextValue by remember(textValue) { mutableStateOf(textValue) }

    val myComposeView = remember {
        MyComposable().apply {
            setContent { Text(newTextValue) }
        }
    }

    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
        Text("Title: $newTextValue")
        myComposeView.myComposable?.invoke()
    }
}
```

It also doesn't work. The `Text("Title: $newTextValue")` doesn't get updated.

#### 3. Pass in a Mutable State Variable instead.

The only way for it to work is to send in a `textValue: MutableState<String>` instead.

```
@Composable
fun MyComposableFun(textValue: MutableState<String>) {

    val myComposeView = remember {
        MyComposable().apply {
            setContent { Text(textValue.value) }
        }
    }

    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
        Text("Title: ${textValue.value}")
        myComposeView.myComposable?.invoke()
    }
}
```

This is not ideal, as we want to avoid passing mutable state variables down the function.

Comment: What's the issue in item 2 with `var newTextValue by remember(textValue) { mutableStateOf(textValue) }`? Changing it via TextField also changes `Text` in `setContent { Text(newTextValue) }`

Comment: For item 2, somehow when the `textValue` change from the function call, the `setContent { Text(textValue) }` doesn't reflect the change. The issue persist as original

Comment: Another option that you haven't listed is using a `LaunchedEffect` with `textValue` as the key and block that would be a setter method to manually update myComposeView